# Editing dropdown menus after a page has loaded in a WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

Here is my code so far:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/btceUSD#rg30zigHourlyztgSzm1g10zm2g25zv");

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:load_table()");
    }
});
```

This page allows you to edit all the drop-down menus and then create a link that will load the page with those settings. Unfortunately Android's built in WebView doesn't seem to want to play along, and loads the page with the default settings. There are two drop-down menus on this page that need to be changed before I can continue parsing it. I would like to change the two drop-down menus under "Time Period." The first needs to be "1 Month" and the second needs to be "Hourly". This is probably what you are seeing when following my link but WebView loads the page with the default values of "2 Months" and "Daily".

Anyone know how I can go about this? Thanks in advance.

I found those two drop-down menus in the page's source:

```
<select id="r" name="r" class="input" style="width:70px;">
    <option value="1">1 day</option>
    <option value="2">2 days</option>
    <option value="5">5 days</option>
    <option value="10">10 days</option>
    <option value="30">1 month</option>
    <option value="60" selected>2 months</option>
    <option value="90">3 months</option>
    <option value="120">4 months</option>
    <option value="150">5 months</option>
    <option value="180">6 months</option>
    <option value="360">1 year</option>
    <option value="730">2 years</option>
    <option value="1460">4 years</option>
    <option value="2920">8 years</option>
    <option value="">All Data</option>
</select>
<select id="i" name="i" class="input" style="width:60px;">
    <option value="">auto</option>            
    <option value="1-min">1-min</option>            
    <option value="5-min">5-min</option>            
    <option value="15-min">15-min</option>            
    <option value="30-min">30-min</option>            
    <option value="Hourly">Hourly</option>            
    <option value="2-hour">2-hour</option>            
    <option value="6-hour">6-hour</option>            
    <option value="12-hour">12-hour</option>            
    <option value="Daily">Daily</option>            
    <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>            
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like the following:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       webView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
             "document.getElementById('r')[0].value = '" + your_value + "';};");
    }
});
```

This way you will be able to find the HTML `select` element and update its value to whatever you want.